# Friend for nested structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct, nested

I know [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) by Bruce Eckel is not a reference book but I found a strange paragraph and I don't understand if it's still applicable today:

> Making a structure nested doesn’t automatically give it access to
>   private members. To accomplish this, you must follow a particular
>   form: first, declare (without defining) the nested structure, then
>   declare it as a friend, and finally define the structure. The
>   structure definition must be separate from the friend declaration,
>   otherwise it would be seen by the compiler as a non-member.

I actually tried this without declaring the nested structure as a friend and it worked:

```
struct myStruct{
private:
    int bar;
public:
    struct nestedStruct{
        void foo(myStruct *);
    }a;
};

void myStruct::nestedStruct::foo(myStruct * p){
    p->bar = 20;
}
```

Is there still a need to declare a nested structure friend in order to modify the private members of the base class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That quote is wrong. A nested inner class-type has access to all members (including `private`) of the enclosing class-type.

This was not the case in C++98, and your edition probably refers to that version of the standard. In C++03 and C++11 the quote doesn't apply.

#### 11.7 Nested classes [class.access.nest]

> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of
> an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
> shall be obeyed.